# Prove it when $ P(X) = a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots +a_n x^n $

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $ P(X) = a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots +a_n x^n $ and $ m \in \mathbb{N} $, prove that
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[m]{1 + P(x)} - 1}{x} = \frac{a_1}{m} $$

I tried to solve it using induction but nothing good happend please help me

Comment: Just put $y=1+P(x)$ so that $y\to 1$ and $(y-1)/x\to a_1$. Write the expression under limit as $\dfrac{y^{1/m}-1}{y-1}\cdot\dfrac{y-1}{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f(x)=\sqrt[m]{P(x)+1}$, then all you have to do is to compute $f'(0)$.

Comment: This of course is because the limit is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=:f'(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to José Carlos Santos answer you can use the Taylor expansion
$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+o(x^2)$$
with $p(x)$ instead of $x$ (both tend to zero as $x\to 0$) and $a=\frac{1}{m}$

Or even simpler, Bernoulli de l'Hopital:

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[m]{1 + P(x)} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\sqrt[m]{1 + P(x)}\right)'=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{P'(x)}{m}({1 + P(x)})^{(1-m)/m}$$